# where to look for domain knowledge

Tags: nlp

Looking for examples where I can map input keywords with predefined keywords.

For example if I have a list of predefined keywords say ['reptiles', 'mammals'].

Then if I input snake or lizard then reptiles should be the answer and when human or bear etc I insert then mammals should be the answer

Comment: Do you want ontological information, e.g. `a snake is a reptile` and `a bear is a mammal`?

Comment: Yes, I need something like that, can you please tell me where I can start from?

Comment: `WordNet` contains this type of information. You can download it for free or access it via a number of APIs (you didn't say what language you are using)

Comment: I would prefer python as language but being new to this I open to all language, which language will you suggest?

Comment: In that case you want `NLTK`, which has `WordNet` bindings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want ontological information, e.g. `a snake is a reptile` and a `bear is a mammal`? `WordNet` contains this type of information. You can download it for free or access it via a number of APIs. For Python you probably want `NLTK`, see demo [here](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/howto/wordnet.html).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this as well:

http://www.conceptwiki.org/

Concept wiki is often used in biological concept, which might be the case here. 
I haven't tried wordNet before, so I can't tell you which one is better.